# Retrieving Windows Mobile browser history

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, browser-history

How can I retrieve a list of urls a user has visited on a Windows Mobile phone?

I've written a program that successfully retrieves the visited urls in a user's *cache*, using `FindFirstUrlCacheEntry` and `FindNextUrlCacheEntry` - but as I understand it this is not the same as the user's *actual* web history. In any case it does not seem to give correct results.

Edit:
I believe the file I'm looking for is `index.dat`. But it's certainly not in the same place it is on a desktop machine, if it exists at all. And I'm not sure how to parse it. Any experience in this area would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which browser - I have two different ones installed on most of my devices...

Comment: Currently I only care about internet explorer. I'm assuming if browser history is available *at all* in other browsers, it will be easier to access. I'm trying to tackle the most used one first.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

[Windows Mobile Internet Explorer History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995203/windows-mobile-internet-explorer-history)