# Windows Mobile Internet Explorer History

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, windows-mobile, compact-framework, browser-history

How do I grab Internet Explorer's history on Windows Mobile 5.0 in C# running on the Compact Framework 1.0? I only need to get the most recently visited URL. Even if you just know where this is stored, I might be able to figure out the rest from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should normally be stored in '\windows\profiles\guest\History*'

It might however be better to retreive this location from the registry using:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

RegistryKey foldersKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders");
string historyFolder = foldersKey.GetValue("History");
```

Comment: When I look in that spot in the registry it does show that file path. The actual history data seems to be in "/Windows/Profiles/guest/History/History.IE5/index.dat". But when I try to open or copy that file in C# I get a generic IOException. This is despite the fact that I made sure that IE was completely closed before running this code.

Comment: This is the code I used that gives me a generic IOException with a message of "IOException": File.OpenRead("Windows/Profiles/guest/History/History.IE5/index.dat");

Comment: I tried running this on CF 3.5 to see if I would get a better error message. It said that the file was being used by another process. I tried restarting the device and now I can read from the file. I will see if I can get other processes to close from inside my code so I can read from this file when I need to.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but might be worth looking into: http://coding.infoconex.com/post/2009/04/How-do-I-open-a-file-that-is-in-use-in-C.aspx

Comment: I could not figure out the format of the file. I found a better way to accomplish what I was trying to do than examining history. I will mark this as the answer even though it is incomplete as to how you would actually get history from the file.

Answer (score 1):

*If* it's stored in the registry (I'm not saying it is, but it's a reasonable place to investigate), then finding it is easy with the following steps:

- Attach the Remote Registry Editor to the device/emulator
- Export the entire registry to a file on your PC
- Use the browser on the device to generate more history
- Export the entire registry again to a file on your PC
- Use your favorite DIFF program to compare the two registry dumps

If history is stored in the registry, it will come up quickly as the only changes between the files.